# WPF Combobox not resizing

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a combobox with a bunch of values in it. I want to change the width of the combobox when "List" is selected. Here is my current xaml:

```
<ComboBox Name="DataTypeSelector" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=DataItemsBuildWindow, Path=DataContext.Types}" SelectedValue="{Binding DataType}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="160">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="List" Binding="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=DataTypeSelector, Converter={StaticResource ToStringConverter}}">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

This does not work for some reason.

If I change the Setter to this:

```
<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
```

Then the combobox is hidden when "List" is selected. Why is it not working for width?

Comment: In WPF, you normally don't layout your GUI by providing fixed width or height. Does it work when you just set the ComboBox to 80 from the start? I suspect your layout simply doesn't change when you set the Width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A property which is explicitly set on an element (here: `Width="160"`) will override all Styles. You need to move that default width (160) into your Style as well:

```
<ComboBox Name="DataTypeSelector" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=DataItemsBuildWindow, Path=DataContext.Types}" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding DataType}" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="160" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="List" Binding="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=DataTypeSelector, Converter={StaticResource ToStringConverter}}">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```